# How to justify text to a certain length in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, function

I am working on a Javascript function that justifies a paragraph into a certain length (`function justify(str, len`). I have already altered the string to have each line's length be less than or equal to `len`. Now the task is to fill in enough spaces so that a line aligns with the next (pun intended) but I am having trouble. I've tried iterating through a line and adding an additional space to a character if it is a space but that did not really work.

Consider the length to be 30:

Before:

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
'consectetur adipiscing elit',
'sed do eiusmod tempor',
'incididunt ut labore et dolore',
'magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim',
'veniam, quis nostrud',
'exercitation ullamco laboris',
'nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo',
'consequat. Duis aute irure',
'dolor in reprehenderit in',
'voluptate velit esse cillum',
'dolore eu fugiat nulla',
'pariatur. Excepteur sint',
'occaecat cupidatat non',
'proident, sunt in culpa qui',
'officia deserunt mollit anim']
```

After:

```
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit amet,
consectetur  adipiscing  elit,
sed    do    eiusmod    tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam,      quis      nostrud
exercitation  ullamco  laboris
nisi  ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.   Duis  aute  irure
dolor   in   reprehenderit  in
voluptate  velit  esse  cillum
dolore    eu    fugiat   nulla
pariatur.    Excepteur    sint
occaecat     cupidatat     non
proident,  sunt  in  culpa qui
officia  deserunt  mollit anim
```

Current State:

```
function justify(str, len) {
    let tempArray = str.split(' ').filter(word => word.length);
    //removes any empty strings resulting from splitting via the spaces
    let lines = [];
    let justified = '';
    let line = [tempArray.shift()];

    for (let i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        const word = tempArray[i];

        if ((line.join(' ') + ' ' + word).length <= len) {
            line.push(word);
        } else {
            lines.push(line.join(' '));
            line = [word];
        }
    }
    /*seperates the paragraph into lines with lengths less than or equal len 
    and stores them in lines*/


    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        let line = lines[i].split('');
        let justifying = true;

        while (justifying) {
            for (let j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
                if (line[j] === ' ') {
                    line[j] = line[j] + ' ';
                }

                if (line.length === 30) {
                    justifying = false;
                    break
                }

            }
        }

        justified += line.join('') + '\n';
    }
    //attempt to justify the paragraph

    return justified;
}
```

Comment: "Having trouble" does not describe where you got stuck.  Please show us your current code attempt and describe exactly where you got stuck.  We aren't meant to be a coding service that just writes code from scratch for you.  Generally, you should attempt to solve the problem and when you get stuck, you show us your code and post a specific question about exactly what you got stuck on.

Comment: This sort of thing is only going to justify the text if you show it in a monospaced font.  Is that the case?  Also note that justification algorithms typically choose where to break lines such that it minimizes the worst case extra spaces.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to justify monospace text

Answer (score 2):

- Split each line into words
- compute the number of characters in the words
- compute how many spaces you have (numSpacesYouHave = len - totalNumCharsInWords)
- for each word

  - compute how much padding (padding = numSpacesYouHave / num gaps left to fill)
  - subtract the padding from tne numSpacesYouHave
  - pad the word

```js
function justifyLine(line, len) {
  // split line into words
  const words = line.split(/ +/);
  // compute number of characters used by words
  const numChars = words.reduce((len, word) => len + word.length, 0);
  let numSpacesToDistribute = len - numChars;
  return words.map((word, ndx) => {
    const numGaps = words.length - ndx - 1;
    const padding = numSpacesToDistribute / numGaps | 0;
    numSpacesToDistribute -= padding;
    return word.padEnd(word.length + padding);
  }).join('');
}

function justifyLines(lines, len) {
  return lines.map(line => justifyLine(line, len));
}

const lines = [
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'consectetur adipiscing elit',
  'sed do eiusmod tempor',
  'incididunt ut labore et dolore',
  'magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim',
  'veniam, quis nostrud',
  'exercitation ullamco laboris',
  'nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo',
  'consequat. Duis aute irure',
  'dolor in reprehenderit in',
  'voluptate velit esse cillum',
  'dolore eu fugiat nulla',
  'pariatur. Excepteur sint',
  'occaecat cupidatat non',
  'proident, sunt in culpa qui',
  'officia deserunt mollit anim',
];

console.log(justifyLines(lines, 30));
```

note when you compute padding you could use `Math.floor(numSpacesYouHave / num gaps)` or `Math.ceil(numSpacesYouHave / num gaps)`. given `justifyLine('a b c', 6)` the first will generate `a b  c` and the second `a  b c`.

note I agree with jfriend00 you should post your code but I figured odds are regardless of what you posted we'd end up starting over from scratch and posting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padEnd`.

```js
function justify(str, len) {
  let temp = [];
  temp = str.map((val) => {
    val = val.padEnd(len, " ");
    return val
  })
  return temp;
}


let a = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  'consectetur adipiscing elit',
  'sed do eiusmod tempor',
  'incididunt ut labore et dolore',
  'magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim',
  'veniam, quis nostrud',
  'exercitation ullamco laboris',
  'nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo',
  'consequat. Duis aute irure',
  'dolor in reprehenderit in',
  'voluptate velit esse cillum',
  'dolore eu fugiat nulla',
  'pariatur. Excepteur sint',
  'occaecat cupidatat non',
  'proident, sunt in culpa qui',
  'officia deserunt mollit anim'
]

let temp = justify(a, 30);

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Downvoter can you explain the reason, it will help me to update my answer.

Comment: This does not produce the expected result as the OP has given. Spacing should not be at the end of a line, but distributed.

Comment: Does OP want to align lines equally by adding the space after lines?